# Is the specified behaviour of `strptime` defined if date is underspecified, overspecified or inconsistent?

Tags: c, specifications, strptime

I have not found any (or few) indications of the appropriate behaviour for `strptime` if the date is:

1. underspecified: contains not enough data to uniquely fill out `tm` (eg fx `tail = strptime("%Y %p", "2015 p.m", &tm);`)
2. inconsistent: contains possibly more than enough data to fill the `tm`, but the data is inconsistent (eg `tail = strptime("%Y-%m-%d %T %Y", "2015-09-15 07:48:29 2016", tm`, noting that two different years are given)
3. overspecified: contains more than enough data to fill the `tm`, but the data is consistent (eg `tail = strptime("%Y-%m-%d %T %Y", "2015-09-15 07:48:29 2015"`, noting that the year is given twice)
4. invalid: the given data is out of range (eg `tail = strptime("%Y-%m-%d %T", 2015-09-32 07:48:29"`, noting the the 32th in a month of 30 days).

I suppose that case 2 and 4 should/could be considered errors and it should return `"2016"` and `"32 07:48:29"` as error indication, but do it need to fill in the `tm` struct in any way?

I also suppose that case 3 would be considered success and `NULL` should be returned and `tm` filled.

What about case 1? Should/could it be considered successful? I suppose that case 3 has a little bit of 1 in it (since it doesn't get the milliseconds), it sounds reasonable to assume that there are "default" values for fields that are not given in the input data (fx missing second-specification could be interpreted as the seconds being zero).

Or is it that `strptime` is only supposed to blindly fill in the `tm` structure with whatever junk is received in that order? That is the case 2, `strptime` would set year to `2016` because that's the last one seen, and in case 1 it wouldn't alter any other fields than `tm_year` and `tm_hour` (to enforce it to be p.m), leaving the rest of the fields unmodified?

Comment: `strptime` is a POSIX function. I think [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) is the official docs

Comment: @M.M: I think that's an older version of POSIX.  The current version gives [`strptime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html).  I've not reviewed them for differences; they may be very similar.  Notice the header message on the page you link to.

Comment: (1) is answered by "It is unspecified whether multiple calls to strptime() using the same tm structure will update the current contents of the structure or overwrite all contents of the structure. Conforming applications should make a single call to strptime() with a format and all data needed to completely specify the date and time being converted.".  For (2) and (3), my reading is that the directives are processed in order and the result of the second `%Y` will overwrite that of the first. (4) could be specified better but I think it  should cause failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the [reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) given by Jonathan Leffler, I noted *Any other conversion specification [other than white space of normal character] is executed by scanning characters until a character matching the next directive is scanned, or until no more characters can be scanned. These characters, except the one matching the next directive, are then compared to the locale values associated with the conversion specifier. **If a match is found, values for the appropriate tm structure members are set** to values corresponding to the locale information. Case is ignored when matching items in buf such as month or weekday names. If no match is found, strptime() fails and no more characters are scanned.* (emphasize mine).

My understanding of it is that `strptime` should *blindly fill in the tm structure with whatever junk is received in that order*.

And effectively:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    struct tm tm = {0};
    char *tail;

    tail = strptime("2015 pm", "%Y %p", &tm);
    printf("%s", asctime(&tm));
    if (tail != NULL) printf(" [%s]", tail);
    puts("\n");
    tail = strptime("2015-09-15 07:48:29 2016", "%Y-%m-%d %T %Y", &tm);
    printf("%s", asctime(&tm));
    if (tail != NULL) printf(" [%s]", tail);
    puts("\n");
    tail = strptime("2015-09-15 07:48:29 2015", "%Y-%m-%d %T %Y", &tm);
    printf("%s", asctime(&tm));
    if (tail != NULL) printf(" [%s]", tail);
    puts("\n");
    tail = strptime("2015-09-32 07:48:29", "%Y-%m-%d %T", &tm);
    printf("%s", asctime(&tm));
    if (tail != NULL) printf(" [%s]", tail);
    puts("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
Sun Jan  0 12:00:00 2015
 []

Sun Sep 15 07:48:29 2016
 []

Sun Sep 15 07:48:29 2015
 []

Sun Sep 15 07:48:29 2015
```

meaning that 1, 2, and 3 and processed without errors but only the relevant fields of tm struct are modified and but the last occurence, and 4 gives an error.